# Postgres: TRUNCATE and COPY in one transaction

Tags: postgresql, transactions, copy, truncate

I need to execute following transaction in Postgres 9.4:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    TRUNCATE TestTable;
    COPY TestTable FROM '/DATAforTestTable' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
END TRANSACTION;
```

Users must have read access to "old" data in TestTable on time of executing the transaction without waiting of tansaction end. Is it possible? Or I must do it via coping and renaming tables?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I execute `select * from TestTable limit 5;` and I get result only after ending transaction or breaking its.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html):

> TRUNCATE acquires an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on each table it operates on, which blocks all other concurrent operations on the table.

Use `delete`

```
begin;
delete from t;
```

Comment: Yes. I've tried to use delete and It works. Thank you so much!